# Payara Micro Debug via NetBeans

Tags: debugging, payara-micro

I am following this [tutorial](https://info.payara.fish/hubfs/Demystifying%20Microservices%20For%20Java%20EE%20%20Developers%20by%20Payara.pdf?hsCtaTracking=3c4f4981-8be8-4ba7-b6b0-855bb076aa03%7Cfaceb4c2-9506-4b75-b7c6-fa5067c2bfc1) and would execute the 3 apps in debug mode throught NB .I am wondering why payara-micro-maven-plugin plugin doesn't have a debug goal as maven exec plugin ?